# Retrieving an Array of Data from Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to retrieve an array of data which is in a JSON format, and is passed to a React Component. If I use console.log(props), I can see data as follows: { props: {data: [[array]]}}.

The problem I have is that I am not able to drill down into the actual data. I have tried props.data.map and props.map, and both of theses return undefined.

The JSON format is as follows:

```
someData = {
             data: [
                     [
                       { 'id':'1',
                         'name': 'somename'
                        }
                     ]
                   ]
            }
```

Is there another object that I need to drill down to get to the data?

Comment: Looks like it's `props.props.data.map`?  Did you accidentally add an additional props property in there?

Comment: In fact it looks more like `props.props.data[0].map`.  Did you copy paste exactly what you got from the console?

Comment: Thanks - this is what I need

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the Data is in `JSON` format and to retrieve and use the the data in JavaScript, you have to parse it into a JavaScript Object.
You can simply do that using the `JSON.parse()` method to parse it into a object. Just pass the prop into this object before sending it and it will work as expected then.

```
data = JSON.parse(data); // if it was defined using let keyword
```

Then just pass it to the required component.

 You can learn more about `JSON.parse()` from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 1):

The object structure is layered differently than you were expecting. It is encapsulated within an additional object with another props property, and the inner array is wrapped in another array.
`props.props.data[0].map`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = JSON.parse(someData)
data.forEach(element => {
  element.map(item => {
    return item
  })
})
```

if you are exact know there is only one item in array then use somedata.data[0].item;
but parse json first because json is strigfy when we recieve json